# Stop Propagation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to stop the bubbling of event of an inner checkbox to the click event of the `tr` element.

I have the following mark up:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr class="row">
    <td>
      Item 1
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>
      Item 2
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The rows are dynamically added, so to add listeners automatically to dynamically added elements, I used the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').off('click.row').on('click.row', '.row', function() {
    alert(1);
  });
  $('body').off('change.cb').on('change.cb', '.cb', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert(2);
  });
});
```

However the event still bubble up to the `tr` element. I tried also the following:

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
window.event.cancelBubbles = true;
e.bubbles = false;
```

none seemed to work.

I reproduced this issue with JSFiddle:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r714756d/1/)

Comment: You're only stopping the `change` event from propagating up. You'll need to add a click handler too

Answer (score 0):

In this case, there is no event bubbling occuring because you have different events defined on different elements that just so happen to both fire when a mouse clicks on the check box (because you have also clicked a row).

You should either not add the row click event listener at all, or move `stopPropagation` to the the other handler to stop it from firing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').off('click.row').on('click.row', '.row', function() {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert(1);
  });
  $('body').off('change.cb').on('change.cb', '.cb', function(e) {       
    alert(2);
  });
});
```